# On the definition of the relative canonical divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, divisors, minimal-model-program

Fix a field $k$. Let $X,Y$ be normal integral $k$-schemes of finite type and $h: Y \to X$ a proper birational $k$-morphism. Moreover, assume that $X$ is Gorenstein, i.e. it admits a canonical divisor $K_X$ which is Cartier.

Let $K_X$ be a Cartier canonical divisor of $X$ and $K_Y$ a canonical divisor of $Y$, so the divisor
$$K_Y-h^*K_X$$
can be considered. Its linear class is independent of the choices of $K_X$ and $K_Y$.

This in mind, the **relative canonical divisor** of $h$ is usually defined to be the unique divisor in $Y$ supported on the exceptional locus of $h$ which is linearly equivalent to $K_Y-h^*K_X$.
My question is:

> How do we prove the existence and uniqueness of such divisor?

I'm a bit stuck trying to prove this (especially uniqueness) and I can't find any reference in the literature...

I also have two side questions about the relative canonical divisor:

1. When is it effective?
2. Is it related to $\Omega^d_{Y/X}$? Here, $d=\dim X = \dim Y$.

Thank you in advance for your time! Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: As to why it is unique, notice that if if it exceptionally supported, this means that $K_Y$ and $K_X$ agree where $h$ is an isomorphism (in fact, if we pick $K_X$, there is a unique $K_Y$ with this property and visa versa, via an argument building upon the observation below). Indeed, suppose that $K'_Y = K_Y + \mathrm{Div}_Y(f)$ is another canonical divisor.  Then its not difficult to see that $K'_X = K_X + \mathrm{Div}_X(f)$ is the unique canonical divisor that agrees with $K'_Y$ over where $h$ is an isomorphism.  Via a direct computation, one see that $$K'_Y - h^* K'_X = K_Y - h^*K_X$$